# XSLT 2.0: Substring a text value after pipe deliminator

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Here is the current value in the output.

```
2016-09-24|1|SF/CASH|2016-11-28T13:30:35.547-08:00|3063|113847
```

I want the last 6 digits of the string `113847` in the text output file.

Comment: `tokenize('2016-09-24|1|SF/CASH|2016-11-28T13:30:35.547-08:00|3063|113847', '\|')[last()]` gives you the string after the last `|` character.

Answer (score 1):

For something like that, I usually use [`tokenize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)...

**XML Input**

```
<input>2016-09-24|1|SF/CASH|2016-11-28T13:30:35.547-08:00|3063|113847</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/input">
    <output><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(.,'\|')[last()]"/></output>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<output>113847</output>
```